# How to write mysql query to check multiple variable selections where form submit can match 1 0f 5 fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that submits the following:

State
City
Category

My query needs to do the following:

If only state selected - show state results

If state and cat selected - show state and cat results

if state and city selected - show state and city results

if state, city and cat are selected - show state, city, cat results

**The catch is when they submit the city, 3 different fields need to be checked for a match**

This is my query and it doesnt work, I have tried 100 different variations. Sorry for being such a newbie. Thanks for help in advance.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE state=$st AND city1='$_GET[city] OR
city2='$_GET[city]' OR city3='$_GET[city]' OR cat='$_GET[cat]' 
AND  active='1' 
ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT $limitvalue, $limit ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($prow=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
```

Comment: All of your OR conditions should be in () like (city1='$_GET[city] OR
city2='$_GET[city]' OR city3='$_GET[city]' OR cat='$_GET[cat]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally am not very good at doing MySQL query strings, I generally use an sql compiler class similar to this (keep in mind, this is just a quick one). It allows for binding, which you require, especially with `$_GET` values like you have:

```
class ItemQueue
    {
        protected   $sql;
        protected   $wherevals;
        public      $bind;
        public      $compiled;

        public function select($values = false)
            {
                $this->sql[] = "select";
                if($values == false)
                    $this->sql[]    =   "*";
                else
                    $this->sql[]    =   $values;

                return $this;
            }

        public function from($table = false)
            {
                if($table ==false)
                    return $this;

                $this->sql[] = "from `$table`";

                return $this;
            }

         public function where($values = array(),$op = 'and')
            {
                if(!empty($values)) {
                        $this->sql[]    =   'where';
                        foreach($values as $key => $values) {
                                $this->wherevals[]      =   $key.' = :'.$key;
                                // Bind values for injection protection
                                $this->bind[":$key"]    =   $values;
                            }

                        $this->sql[]        =   implode(" $op ",$this->wherevals);
                        // This part is a bit jenky but you get the idea
                        $this->sql[]        =   "and active = '1'";
                    }

                return $this;
            }

        public  function customsql($values = false)
            {
                if($values != false) {
                        $this->sql[]    =   $values;
                    }

                return $this;
            }

        public  function Fetch()
            {
                // Implode entire sql statement
                $this->compiled =   implode(" ", $this->sql);

                return $this;
            }
    }

    // Post/Get values
    $_POST['cat']   =   'cattest';
    $_POST['city']  =   'Reno';
    $_POST['state'] =   'Nevada';

    // Arbitrary limits
    $limit          =   1;
    $limitvalue     =   1;
    // Create instance
    $tester =   new ItemQueue();
    // Just set some array filtering/validating
    if(isset($_POST['cat']) && !empty($_POST['cat']))
        $array['cat']   =   $_POST['cat'];

    if(isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city']))
        $array['city']  =   $_POST['city'];

    if(isset($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['state']))
        $array['state'] =   $_POST['state'];

    // Make the query
    $query  =   $tester->select()->from("items")->where($array,"or")->customsql("ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT $limitvalue, $limit");

    // Here is the sql statement
    echo $query->Fetch()->compiled;

    // Bind array
    print_r($query->bind);
```

**Gives you:**

```
select * from `items` where cat = :cat or city = :city or state = :state and active = '1' ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 1, 1

Array
    (
        [:cat] => cattest
        [:city] => Reno
        [:state] => Nevada
    )
```

*Note, this requires you to use a proper connection (PDO works best in this case).*

Comment: Nice class! The only thing I see is the limit and limit values are for paging. Setting an absolute value wont work because its dynamic. I'll just remove it from the class and it should work great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like operator precedence? When you are grouping related conditions where only one of which must be true, you want something of this form:

```
(column1 = 'value' OR column2 = 'value') 
AND (column3 = 'value' OR column4 = 'value')
```

[You may want to read up on SQL injection, too.](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go! My sql statements are not named $sql, I just used that here. Would that matter?

Answer (score 0):

your code contains typo , use

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE state=$st AND city1='$_GET[city]' OR
city2='$_GET[city]' OR city3='$_GET[city]' OR cat='$_GET[cat]' 
AND  active='1' 
ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT $limitvalue, $limit ";
```

Check on 1st line of your code you have `city1='$_GET[city] OR .......` which is wrong `city1='$_GET[city]' OR`is correct

Comment: Its just a typo here, I hand wrote it real quick. I actually use an array like this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE $searchfields AND  active='1'` It was just easier to write out the specific terms